# External List and External ContentTypes passing persistence errors back to the user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, bcs, sharepoint2010-bcs

I have created an External Content Type in my Sharepoint 2010 installation that gets its data through a WCF Service from a remote database. I have implemented all the CRUD operations without issue.

I have created a list instance in Visual Studio 2010 and I have added a custom newform to the instance so when a user selects New Item while browsing the list my custom form is the one used. This works well. However when a user inputs data for a new item and presses Save I need to be able to return to the user any errors that might arise from the external system.

I can't figure out how to get an event or handle to the BDCModel in my code behind of my custom form that will allow me to post back an error if for instance the WCF Service times out or the remote database is not available for some reason.

Governance has declared that we are not allowed to use the Sharepoint Designer or InfoPath forms to I have to do this in Visual Studio.

Can anyone point out tutorials for intercepting errors returned from BDCModel Create and Update methods and posting them back to the user through the code behind of my custom form or do I have to implement the entire save procedure myself with a totally custom form that overrides the Save?

I would rather not have to do that. I have also been told that I cannot use a custom webpart to implement this with the client object model unless there is absolutely no way to solve this using the OOTB external list and custom forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's permissions (it's always permissions) - the backend user (likely the App Pool Account) doesn't have permissions - check the System Application event log then check the Security log. The SharePoint ULS log might help as well.

Comment: Permissions doesn't appear to be the issue. I cannot find a place in the code behind or in the bdcmodel code where I can bubble persistence errors back to the user. All the CRUD operations work, but when I introduce an error on purpose like taking the WCF services offline I can't get a message back to the user saying that there was a problem contacting the service. All I can do is throw an exception and get an ugly error window. I am looking for an avenue to gracefully handle exceptions thrown from the external system.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's probably true - the BDC doesn't give us very much in the way of trapping. However, you can add code to push messages to the ULS log - that should at least give you some way to trace back.

Comment: It is interesting that with a web portal they would add this BCS technology, but not give the developer any insight into the lifecycle so you could tap in and keep tabs on what is going on. That was the answer I expected though as I seem to be finding everywhere I look that you can't really "handle" errors unless you are willing to build a custom WebPart. I am trying to collect enough information so I can present it to governance and prove to them it can't really be done which is a pain =).